# No keyword with name 'Remove String' found

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to get the number 70 from the below mentioned string:

> Showing 1 to 50 of 70 entries

I have tried the below code:

```
${text} = Get Text xpath=//div[@id='DataTables_Table']
Page Should Contain Showing 1 to
${edited_text} = Remove String ${text} Showing 1 to 50 of
```

But i am getting the below mentioned error:

> No keyword with name 'Remove String' found.

I am getting the same error even if I use the following keywords:

> Get Substring, Replace String

Comment: here is HTML code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When keywords aren't found, this typically means that the library has not been loaded. With the exception of the `BuiltIn` library, all others need to be declared. A full working example of your code is below:

```
*** Setting ***
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
tc
    ${text}           Set Variable    Showing 1 to 50 of 70 entries
    ${edited_text}    Remove String     ${text}     Showing 1 to 50 of

    ${matches}        String.Get Regexp Matches    ${text}    [0-9]{1,2}
    Log               "Max is:" ${matches[2]}
```

As you're intention is to match the 3rd digit group, the regular expression match seems like the cleanest approach.

Comment: Hi A. Kootstra Thanks for your suggestion it worked for me :)